# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Mystery

Tags: ios4, nsmutablearray

I could use a little help on this one. I narrowed the crash source down to NSMutableArray viewControllers by commenting out the release statement in dealloc.

Code:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.numSlides; i++) {
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

self.viewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];

// Later on in dealloc:
[viewControllers release], viewControllers = nil;
```

In the main.m file [ int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); ] we get:
Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

When I comment out the release for viewControllers -> no crash but memory leak.

Are you out there Obi-Wan - you are our last hope.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine; without seeing any of the rest of it, I’d guess that your `viewControllers` property is declared as `assign` rather than `retain`. If that isn’t it, try running the static analyzer (Product > Analyze or Cmd-Shift-B); it can usually catch that kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Noah - tried that to no avail before posting. It was a good idea. Analyzer didn't give any answers but Instruments gave me a Zombie.

Comment: Now I am getting a memory leak on Instruments on this line if I comment out [viewControllers release], viewControllers = nil; in Dealloc. NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; This is very strange - I have seen a number of posts about this problem but never a solution that passes Leak Test on Instruments - Static Analyzer doesn't pick it up. Any help would be appreciated.